# Visual grouping inside a CardView when using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, adapter, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

My data set has instances of "item". I want some arbitrary number of these to appear inside a CardView:

```
item 1
item 2
 ~~~~~~~~
| item 3 |
| item 4 |
| item 5 |
 ~~~~~~~~
item 6
item 7    
item 8
item 9
 ~~~~~~~~~
| item 10 |
| item 11 |
 ~~~~~~~~~
item12
```

... and so on.

It seems my options are:

- Not use recycler view at all, but iterate through the list and inflate cardviews and add following n items in them. This probably isn't the most performance friendly approach.
- Use recycler view but also use item decoration to draw card-like borders around them.
- Some other method I don't know (custom layout managers?).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is the question/problem?

Comment: What is the best/recommended practice for achieving the said layout, when using a recyclerview.

Comment: I don't think there is one. From your listed options using decorations seems ok. Also consider using custom adapter with multiple view types. However, your question does not show any effort and clear problem, please read ["how do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)